# Renaming names in a dataset with commas and fullstops

Tags: r

I am trying to rename some countries in my data but I seem to be having an issue with one. I wish to rename these following countries but I get an error when trying to rename 'Egypt, Arab Rep.' to `Egypt'

```
data

Country_Name               value
Egypt, Arab Rep.       2192
Syrian Arab Republic   4998
Turkiye                8230
```

code used to rename

```
data = data %>% rename(Egypt = "Egypt, Arab Rep.") %>% rename(Syria = "Syrian Arab Republic") %>% rename(Turkey = "Turkiye")
```

error message received

```
`Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column_Name `Egypt, Arab Rep.` doesn't exist.`
```

Comment: your column is named `Country`; What you want to rename is the values inside of the `Country`-column.

Comment: Only for start: `data = data %>% mutate(Country = gsub("Egypt", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", Country, fixed=T)) %>% mutate(Country= gsub("Syria", "Syrian Arab Republic", Country, fixed=T)) %>% mutate(Country = gsub("Turkey", "Turkiye", Country, fixed=T))`

Comment: @Mossa Sorry forgot to call it the same thing on my example data, all sorted now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` way of doing this would be using the `case_when` function

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Country = c("Egypt, Arab Rep.", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Turkiye"),
                 value = c(2192, 4998, 8230))

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Country = dplyr::case_when(
    Country == "Egypt, Arab Rep." ~ "Egypt",
    Country == "Syrian Arab Republic" ~ "Syria",
    TRUE ~ Country
  ))
```

**RESULT:**

```
  Country value
1   Egypt  2192
2   Syria  4998
3 Turkiye  8230
```